# P value and sample size

Tags: p-value, sample

Say for a 2x2 experiment, the power analysis said the sample size should be over 1000 to detect 0.1 effect size. Right now, with the sample size of below 100, the effect size of .12 is insignificant with the p value being 0.8 (very far from .05)

Is it fair to say that even if I attain the required over 1000 sample, the result is less likely to be significant?

Comment: I don't think so, no.

Comment: Less likely than what?

Comment: @PeterFlom less likely than those with the P value close to .05

Comment: It's a bit unclear why you want to make such a statement. Is it to "call it a day" and stop collecting data? Or is there another reason? Knowing your reasons may help answering you.

Comment: @J-J-J  We did an online experiment with less than 100 student sample as students weren't enthusaistic in helping out.  The sample size is far from the power analysis required for a medium effect size (which is more than 200).  But anyway, I did the analysis as it is and found the manipulation is not significant.  And I am being told the manipulation failed regardless of sample size as the P value is like .8 ...  I am not sure about it.  If that's not true, maybe I will use my own money with crowdsourcing platform....   But I got to be cautious as the money is really from my own pocket....

Comment: @JenniferLau Note that you can edit your post to add all this information there, instead of in the comment section (so much more people on this website will see it and offer suggestions). As a side note, it's been my experience that students answer more to surveys if you make a short but personal presentation (even by e-mail) of the study to some student elected representatives (or presidents of student associations, etc.) and ask them to mention/distribute the survey to the students they are in contact with. Not sure if it would be adequate in your context, but who knows.